# svnadmin dump --deltas

Tags: svn

Are there any particular reasons why I would not want to use the `--deltas` argument, either for an incremental or a complete `svnadmin dump`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some cons listed in svnbook.  Here's a snippet from [**the online svnbook**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html):

> There are, however, disadvantages to
>   using this option—deltified dump files
>   are more CPU-intensive to create,
>   cannot be operated on by
>   svndumpfilter, and tend not to
>   compress as well as their nondeltified
>   counterparts when using third-party
>   tools such as gzip and bzip2.

Comment: argh. it would have been nice if there was a 3rd option, some kind of "smart" delta where the raw file was compared with a regular delta and entropy measures calculated for both, with the smaller entropy method used. Binary files are more efficiently stored in raw form, text files with minor changes are more efficiently stored in delta form.

Comment: I'm sure the wouldn't mind some extra dev help :)

Comment: I know it is just a one person's data point, but I found delta to be much much smaller than gzip of a dump.